# Do we use commas in similar scenarios

Tags: punctuation

Pretending to do things he can hardly do while others look at him in awe(,) is his thing.

Should there be a comma there? If so, what are some other similar constructions where you'd use a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not use a comma there.

The structure of the sentence is fundamentally "X is Y".  You don't use a comma there, because that would make it "X, is Y" and you don't use a comma between the subject and the verb there.

Your example sentence has a very long *X* (the subject of the sentence) but it is fundamentally just one phrase: "Pretending to do things he can hardly do while others look at him in awe" is just one singular subject.

Comment: Could help me with one more thing? And this one's a participle phrase.